# bounded function in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

There is a classic problem in Analysis stating that for integrable $f$ and $g$ bounded and measurable then their product is integrable. Now I am trying to show if $g$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that its product with $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d \ \forall f$ integrable, then $g$ is bounded outside a set of measure $0$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144586/discussion-on-question-by-c-master-bounded-function-in-mathbbrd); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved by looking at a specific sequence of sets, namely the sets $A_n = \{x \mid n \leq g < n+1\}$.

We work by contrapositive. If $g$ is unbounded, we want to find a function $f \in L^1$ such that $fg \notin L^1$. Since $g$ is not bounded outside a set of measure 0, there are infinitely many sets $A_n = \{x \mid n \leq g < n+1\}$ such that $\mu(A_n) > 0$.
Without loss of generality, assume this happens for a positive sequence of integers $n_k$ (consider $-g$ otherwise), which may be taken strictly increasing.

We have a strictly increasing sequence $n_k$ such that $\mu(A_{n_k})>0$. Since it is strictly increasing, $n_k \geq k$. Let us try to find the desired $f$ as
$$ f = \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k 1_{A_{n_k}}$$
for a well chosen sequence of positive real numbers $c_k$. We want $\int f < \infty$ and $ \int fg = \infty$.

$$
\int f d\mu = \sum c_k \mu(A_{n_k}),
$$
$$
\int fg d\mu = \sum c_k \int_{A_{n_k}} g d\mu \geq \sum c_k \mu(A_{n_k}) \ n_k
$$
since $g \geq n_k$ on $A_{n_k}$.
We want to find a sequence $c_k$ such that the first sum is finite and the second sum is infinite.

We can take
$$c_k = {1\over \mu(A_{n_k})} {1 \over k \, n_k}.$$
The first sum is equal to $\sum {1\over k \, n_k} \leq \sum {1 \over k^2} < \infty$ since $n_k \geq k$. The second one is equal to $\sum {1\over k} = \infty$.

Comment: I don't know the proof. Intuitively I thought constructing a sequence of sets would be the way to go.

Comment: I was thinking $A_n = \{x \mid -n \leq g < n\}$

Comment: It is slightly easier with $A_n = \{x \mid n \leq g < n+1\}$.

Comment: could you expand on your answer please?

Comment: I think your answer (i.e. the proof you are preparing) is already in the proposed duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3766315/a-question-for-a-measurable-function-g-on-a-finite-measure-space-such-that-fg